# Magento2 - How to develop for Magento Enterprise Edition

Tags: magento2, development, licensing

One of our client asked us to implement an ecommerce solution based on `Magento2` Enterprise Edition for which they have a license.

We, as contractors, don't hold the license, and the client don't want to share theirs with our developers (which are many and spread all around the world), which is perfectly understandable.

What is the recommended way to develop a site based on `Magento2` `EE`? Can we just target `Magento2` CE for our developments?

Answer (score 0):

In case a functionality closely tied to additional magento extensions - such as reward points, gift cards, you should have the EE distributive.
In common case if you use Service Contract in development you can risk.

More frequency problems in EE related with schedule update feature:

1) In resource models for some entities and some cases (product, categories, etc) developer uses `entity_id` directly - for EE the primary key is `row_id`. `entity_id` is not the unique field. Developer should use EntityMetadataInterface::getLinkField() for determine the primary key.

2) Developer adds a custom section to entities, which support schedule update (such as review for product - no standard EAV attributes) and doesn't check the ability to create schedule update - he should correctly hide or add custom section to schedule update form.